# Why is 'repeat' defined using a local definition?

Tags: haskell

Looking at how [`repeat` definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#repeat) is see:

```
repeat x = xs where xs = x : xs
```

What's the reason for having the local `xs` definition here, instead of just defining

```
repeat x = x : repeat x
```

I suspect it has something to do with compiler optimizations enabled due to better inlining, but I'm really just guessing. Does anybody know the actual reason(s)?